# How to define loss for sparse line detection?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, loss

So I look at the image->mask problem. Having approximately three 2px wide by 100px+ length lines (curves) on 256x256 images. I want to maximize

1. line length
2. line thin structure
3. line accuracy

at the same time. Tho to design a loss that would focus on thin long lines?

So currently I try:

```
def lines_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        mask_lines = K.greater_equal(y_true, 0.95)
        mask_empty = K.less(y_true, 0.95)
        lines_masked = tf.boolean_mask(y_pred - y_true, mask_lines)
        empty_masked = tf.boolean_mask(y_pred - y_true, mask_empty)
        base = K.mean(K.square(lines_masked)) +  K.mean(K.square(empty_masked))
        loss_value = base 

        return loss_value
```

It keeps a relative balance yet the network seems to overtrain too fast (validation loss >> train loss) and produce rain like images - all lines are short and there are way too much of them (imagine raindrops). Example:

[image]

Had to be only 3 long lines:

[image]

Comment: Could you please give more information, e.g., your model's code, a few input, and their output from the model and their expected results?

Comment: I would look into the Dice Loss if I were you, it's usually very well suited to edge detection/segmentation. However, hard to tell you more without more examples of your use case.

Comment: can you please accept the answer if it worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents given that I understand the problem definition correctly.

I suggest that you i) detect and ii) segment the lines using openCV first to create the masks, i.e. (pseudo) ground-truth. Having the lines segmented means that you have pairs of (image, line_segmentations_inside_image). Finally, you can choose and train any decent CNN (among the plethora of off-the-shelf ones) with standard literature losses such as MSE etc. using those (image, line_segmentations_inside_image).

(Of course, you can directly apply an already trained CNN that can segment objects, see transfer learning)

Please find some openCV code that can do the line segmentation for you.

**First, get the gray image and process GaussianBlur.**

```
img = cv2.imread('src.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

kernel_size = 5
blur_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(kernel_size, kernel_size),0)
```

**Second, process edge detection use Canny.**

```
low_threshold = 50
high_threshold = 150
edges = cv2.Canny(blur_gray, low_threshold, high_threshold)
```

**Then, use HoughLinesP to get the lines. You can adjust the parameters for better performance depending on the values you mentioned and are custom to your problem.**

```
rho = 1  # distance resolution in pixels of the Hough grid
theta = np.pi / 180  # angular resolution in radians of the Hough grid
threshold = 15  # minimum number of votes (intersections in Hough grid cell)
min_line_length = 50  # minimum number of pixels making up a line
max_line_gap = 20  # maximum gap in pixels between connectable line segments
line_image = np.copy(img) * 0  # creating a blank to draw lines on

# Run Hough on edge detected image
# Output "lines" is an array containing endpoints of detected line segments
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, rho, theta, threshold, np.array([]),
                    min_line_length, max_line_gap)

for line in lines:
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
    cv2.line(line_image,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,0,0),5)
```

**# Optional visualisation: Draw the lines on the original image**

```
lines_edges = cv2.addWeighted(img, 0.8, line_image, 1, 0)
```